# why the execution order of output is not as expected

Tags: c, stdout, stdin, fflush

I'm learning c and I got stuck in some codes as below from a tutorial.

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main() {
    fprintf(stdout, "This is to stdout. ");
    fprintf(stderr, "This is to stderr. ");
    fprintf(stdout, "This is also to stdout. ");
}
```

and the result they got is

```
This is to stderr. This is to stdout. This is also to stdout.
```

which is out of order
but what I got is

```
This is to stdout. This is to stderr. This is also to stdout.
```

which is in order.
So that's so weird, Why I got a different result?
(the tut I refer to is https://www.journaldev.com/39049/fflush-in-c)

Comment: Usually `stdout` is **line-buffered** and `stderr` is **unbuffered**.

Comment: and stdout may be set to unbuffered to flush immediately

Comment: @KamilCuk It totally make sense to me, but I got different result after executing same codes as above

Comment: How did you run the program? From the command line? With output directly to the terminal window or sent to a pipe or file?

Comment: @EricPostpischil run by cmd, and I've found the problem that the stdout  is unbuffered in the implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe in your implementation, `stdout` is **unbuffered**. Check your documentation.

You may want to try [`setvbuf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setvbuf.html) to revert `stdout` to **line-buffered**: use, for example, `setvbuf(stdout, 0, _IOLBF, 1000);` right at the beginning of `main()` **before any other use of `stdout`**.

---

Usually `stdout` is **line-buffered** and `stderr` is **unbuffered**.

**unbuffered** : data is sent, by the OS, from the stream to the device as soon as it is available.

**line-buffered**: data is sent to the device when a newline (or a limit) is reached.

**fully buffered**: data is sent to the device when the buffer is full.

```
fprintf(stdout, "hello"); // "hello" is kept in buffer because no newline
fprintf(stderr, "again"); // "again" is sent to the device immediately
fprintf(stdout, "world"); // "world" is kept in buffer
// ...
return 0;                 // buffer (now containing "helloworld") is sent to the device at program completion
```

Comment: It's not your "fault" :-) Some installations (especially with an IDE) change the default buffering mode of `stdout` (and maybe other streams).

Comment: I got another question, why the order doesn't back to "normal" after I add a newline right after "hello". (i.e.hello\n).

Comment: Maybe your `stdout` is fully-buffered. Data is only sent to device when buffer (maybe 1K bytes?) is full. A newline should force data to the device when the stream is line-buffered! *But there can be various levels of buffering among the different interfaces data must pass trhough from your code to the device (code, implementation, OS, device software, device hardware, ...) and no real way to manage all this mess from your C code.*